# Google Sheets - Conditional Formatting - One Cell Based on Another Cell Text

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I would like to conditional format the "N - I - P" cells based on the cell data in Column A. Each row might have a different value in Column A. Is there a quicker way to conditional format?

[Link to Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cpJ2KUuRAsLaR7VGLZRyIfSkm4GOHNr3xftLNqZ2CUo/edit?usp=sharing) with Example.

[image]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Custom Formula.

#### Rule:

[image: setup]

#### Formula:

```
=IF(AND(A1=E1,NOT(ISBLANK(E1))),1,0)
```

or

```
=AND(A1=E1,NOT(ISBLANK(E1)))
```

Just change `E` to `D` and `C` for other columns. Do not forget to also update the **Apply to range** per color.

#### Output:

[image: output]